# Create new columns in dataframe using a dictionary mapping

Tags: python, pandas

I created a map where they key is a string and the value is a tuple. I also have a dataframe that looks like this

```
d = {'comments' : ['This is a bad website', 'The website is slow']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

The maps value for `This is a bad website` contains something like this

```
[("There isn't enough support to our site",
  'Staff Not Onsite',
  0.7323943661971831),
 ('I would like to have them on site more frequently',
  'Staff Not Onsite',
  0.6875)]
```

What I want to do now is create 6 new columns inside the data frame using the first two tuple entries in the map.

So what I would want is something like this

```
d = {'comments' : ['This is a bad website', 'The website is slow'],
     'comment_match_1' : ['There isn't enough support to our site', ''],
     'Negative_category_1' : ['Staff Not Onsite', ''],
     'Score_1' : [0.7323, 0],
     'comment_match_2' : ['I would like to have them on site more frequently', ''],
     'Negative_category_2' : ['Staff Not Onsite', ''],
     'Score_2' : [0.6875, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this are greatly appreciated.

Here is how I generated the map for reference

```
d = {}
a = []
for x, y in zip(df['comments'], df['negative_category']):
    for z in unlabeled_df['comments']:
        a.append((x, y, difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, z).ratio()))
        d[z] = a
```

Thus when I execute this line of code

```
d['This is a bad website']
```

I get

```
[("There isn't enough support to our site",
  'Staff Not Onsite',
  0.7323943661971831),
 ('I would like to have them on site more frequently',
  'Staff Not Onsite',
  0.6875), ...]
```

Comment: How does the mapping dictionary looks like? Can you give an example with `key:value` pair?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I added an example, the `...` indicates that there is a lot more tuples. I am just interested in the first two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate a `mapping` dictionary by flattening the values corresponding to each of the key in the dictionary, then with the help of `Series.map` substitute the values in the column `comments` from mapping dictionary, finally create new dataframe from these substituted values and `join` this new dataframe with the `comments` column:

```
mapping = {k: np.hstack(v) for k, v in d.items()}
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['comments'].map(mapping).dropna().tolist()))
```

---

```
                comments                                       0                 1                   2                                                  3                 4       5
0  This is a bad website  There isn't enough support to our site  Staff Not Onsite  0.7323943661971831  I would like to have them on site more frequently  Staff Not Onsite  0.6875
1    The website is slow                                     NaN               NaN                 NaN                                                NaN               NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Could we only take the first two tuples in the mapping though? There was a lot more than just two but I am only interested in the first two.

Comment: @justanewb If you want only first two tuples you can slice them before using `hstack` for example you could do `np.hstack(v[:2])`

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I need but the thing is I want to do this for each comment in the dataframe, does that make sense?

Comment: In other words say that there was a value for `The website is slow` then I want to take its associated first two tuples and put them into the `0 1 2 3 4 5` columns